# Performance Discrepancy in LeetCode Problem 238: Code with 2 Loops Takes 2ms, Code with 3 Loops Takes 1ms

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I'm facing a perplexing performance issue while working on LeetCode Problem 238, which involves finding an array where each element is the product of all elements in the input array except itself. Despite both of my code snippets having similar time complexities, I've noticed a substantial execution time difference. The code snippet with two loops takes around 2 milliseconds to run, whereas the code snippet with three loops completes in approximately 1 millisecond.

This problem is specifically related to LeetCode Problem 238. Below are the two code snippets I've been working with:

Code Snippet 1 (2 Loops) (My Code):

```
public int[] productExceptSelf(int[] nums) {
    int[] result = new int[nums.length];
    result[0] = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++){
        result[i+1] = nums[i] * result[i];
    }

    int product = 1;
    for(int i = nums.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
        result[i-1] = nums[i] * result[i - 1] * product;
        product = product * nums[i];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Code Snippet 2 (3 Loops) (Code that takes 1ms):

```
public int[] productExceptSelf(int[] nums) {
    int res[] = new int[nums.length];
    
    for(int num: nums) {
        num = 1;
    }

    int prefix = 1;
    for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        res[i] = prefix;
        prefix *= nums[i];
    }
    int postfix = 1;
    for(int i=nums.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        res[i] *= postfix;
        postfix *= nums[i];
    }

    return res;
}
```

Both code snippets have an O(n) time complexity and solve the same problem, which makes the performance difference even more intriguing.

Comment: What's the idea behind this: `for (int num: nums) {num = 1; }` ?

Comment: That's not my code; I found it on LeetCode as the best answer for this problem. I wrote my own code with two loops. However, after running both codes several times, I noticed that my code (the one with two loops) consistently took 2 milliseconds to execute, while the code I found took only 1 millisecond. I'm having trouble understanding the reason behind this difference.

Comment: The first performs 4−4 multiplications, and the second performs 3 multiplications. The first performs 7-5 additions/subtractions, and the second performs 2+1 additions/subtractions. Moreover, to get more reliable timing results, you should benchmark over a longer timeslice then just 2 milliseconds, and not on a shared server, but a dedicated machine.

Comment: @trincot Thanks, buddy! That's a very concise answer. I get it now. I hadn't considered that perspective before.

Comment: As hinted in the first comment, the first loop in the second code does nothing except take time (unless the jit compiler is smart enough to remove it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about how JDK optimizes the code, so I can only give some guesses:

1. In CodeBlock 2, the first loop is possible to be optimized by JDK because it has no influence on the array.
2. Compared with CodeBlock 1, CodeBlock 2 have less addressing operations, which consumes lots of time.

Finally, the difference between 1ms and 2ms cannot be treated with 2 times, and maybe it's a good idea to construct a bigger array(length of 10^7 or even 10^8), then run a "benchmark" to get a longer time to compare.